# Antlr 4 IDE installation Failure

Tags: eclipse, installation, antlr4, ubuntu-18.04

Following a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, and subsequent installation of Eclipse (Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)) i have tried to install the Antlr4 ide using "Help -> Eclipse Marketplace", Search for Antlr4 and click Install (ANTLR 4 IDE 0.3.6). I am then given the error below:

[image]

My Java version is as follows:

```
%java -version 
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Also installing jdk 11 resulted in this:

```
openjdk-11-jdk-headless is already the newest version (10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1)
```

I effectively get the same error when installing from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/antlr-4-ide.

Has this error been seen before, and is there a solution ?

Comment: Do you use OpenJDK to run Eclipse and if yes, which version?

Comment: @howlger OpenJDK is not installed.

Comment: Which Java JRE/JDK do you use to run Eclipse?

Comment: @howlger - Java versioning added to question.

Comment: @howlger Double checked openjdk installation - Info Added.

Comment: [I thought it was OpenJDK 8 or 9](https://eclipsehowl.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/hello-openj9-on-windows-i-didnt-expect-you-so-soon/), but obviously it's not.

Comment: @howlger Would reverting to 8 or 9 be a possible solution ?

Comment: Use OpenJDK 10, HotSpot 8, 9 or 10 to run Eclipse and avoid OpenJDK < 10 (as you did). Just to be sure, look in _Help > About Eclipse...: Installation Details: Configuration_ on which Java JRE Eclipse is running (lines starting with `java.`).

Comment: @howlger - Thanks - Ill try this tomorrow.

Comment: Solved this by purging all java & eclipse from my system, & re-installing, & not using the existing (copied) workspace. I suspect that the workspace settings confused the installers across versions. @howlger - Thanks for your help.